REST services: why should I bother with supporting multiple resource representations?
I'm trying to wrap my head around REST principles, and the multiple representations principle confuses me. It'd appear to me that server side could be greatly simplified by having a single canonical representation of any given resource. Why should I add multiple format support?
"But different clients will have different needs!"
Yes, and? Isn't it client's job to interpret the data they receive from the server? Some wacky client might prefer receiving a uu-encoded tar file, but should I add that ahead of time, too?
Basically, it appears to me so:
a) if server-side developer can influence client-side development (both sides are developed together), they should settle on a single canonical representation and use it.
b) if server-side developer can not influence client-side development (say, they are making a public API), they should implement a single canonical representation and let the clients adapt to it.
Obviously, I'm getting something wrong here, but what?

Your point b is not realistic for a widely used api with clients being added to existing apps in many different technologies. I you want lots of takeup then make it easier for clients.

So your point is, that providing variety in representation takes up resources short term, but boosts the project long term. Did I understand it correctly?

Essentially yes.

@JohnWilliams I guess it's a reason. Thanks.
Would you kindly repost your comment as an answer?

Your point b is not realistic for a widely used api with clients being added to existing apps in many different technologies. If you want lots of takeup then make it easier for clients.

JSON as a representation has some downfalls. For example, it is less expressive and flexible than XML, meaning there are restrictions on the complexity and variety of data structures and schemas. Additionally, JSON does not support comments, namespaces, or attributes, making it difficult to add metadata or annotations. JSON does not support a wide variety of types yet seeing as it was built for javascript clients originally.
XML solves many of these challenges. However there are also less verbose representations that take less space over the wire and may seem more intuitive. YAML, CSV, https://docs.internetobject.org/ to list a few.
When creating an API, one goal you might have is to pick as few contentTypes as you can, which will satisfy as many different clients as you can.
Another aspect of this question does not relate to content types but is still in the realm of "multiple representations" that you are asking about. Representations also consists of all fields that are present in the representation, so if you're api takes 3 fields as required inputs in some cases and other times 4 fields are required in another endpoint of the same or a different api, those are different representations. You can use the presence or absence of fields or value in those fields to alter the api logic, and the client logic. This is usually done to limit the number of endpoints and capture complex interaction in the code. The resource is the same. Perhaps the value of the ID field of a resource if equal to 0 is used to add a new object with a quantity of "1", or, that same ID field, if > 0 is used to increment that same quantity on the existing object. You might complain that this isn't RESTFUL in some way, but i'm not trying to talk about REST right now. And sometimes it's very nice from a clients perspective to have a way to increment something even when that thing must be created first, in the same way that you would increment it from an api perspective n+1 times, without changing REST verbs and more in between.
To you're earlier statement:

if server-side developer can influence client-side development (both sides are developed together), they should settle on a single canonical representation and use it.

The best explanation i've seen for REST was given here: https://twobithistory.org/2020/06/28/rest.html
Its an entertaining read. In a nutshell: why are you using REST if you control the API's and the clients? but i don't mean to say you are wrong to do so, simply that it takes intentional forethought. It could be the case that within you're organization, you in theory do control both ends of the development there, however in practice your organization is large enough that it's grappling with the anarchic scalability problem within.
